# get user meta by user id in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I update Many Meta in current user and i want get all of meta

```html
   <?php 
    $new_user_id = 1 ;
    $stats = test;
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id() , 'add-user-id-'.$new_user_id, $stats);

$new_user_id = 2 ;
    $stats = test;
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id() , 'add-user-id-'.$new_user_id, $stats);
 ?>
```

How can I get Any Meta Like 'add-user-id-[array of all users id ]' ?

Example : I want List Of all Users Id saved in current user

Answer (score 0):

You can get all user_meta and then find the ones you need. For example, something like this:

```
$new_user_id = 1 ;
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "add-user-id-$new_user_id", $new_user_id );

$new_user_id = 2 ;
update_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), "add-user-id-$new_user_id", $new_user_id );

$find_meta_ids = [1, 2];
$find_key_prefix = 'add-user-id-';

$output = [];
$all_meta = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id() );

foreach ( $all_meta as $key => $value ) {
    $key_id = array_pop( explode( $find_key_prefix, $key ) );
    if( in_array( $key_id, $find_meta_ids ) ) {
        $output[$key] = $value[0];
    }
}

var_dump( $output );
```

Result: `array(2) { ["add-user-id-1"]=> string(1) "1" ["add-user-id-2"]=> string(1) "2" }`